# imagemagick mean image sequence and ignore alpha channel

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, mean, alpha

I want to get the mean of a sequence of images by using Imagemagick. Therefore I use the following command:

```
convert *.png -evaluate-sequence mean MEAN.png
```

Each of my images does contain an alpha channel. What I want is: Combine all the images by ignoring the alpha channel.

When I combine the images, the alpha channel is considered in the "mean" method and my final image has transparency. That isn't what I want.

Result:

[image: mean transparency]

I tried to add the parameter -alpha off, but then Imagemagick converts the alpha channel to black.

```
convert *.png -alpha off -evaluate-sequence mean MEAN.png
```

Result:

[image: mean with alpha off]

**Photoshop does it right.** I load all images in a stack and create a smart object. When I use the "mean" method in Photoshop, the alpha channel is not considdered in the final result.

Result that I want with Imagemagick:

[image: mean with photoshop]

Does someone have an idea how to do that with Imagemagick?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Try adding `-channel RGB` before `-evaluate-sequence`.

Comment: Aah! I can see the images now! It works fine with version 7.x of **ImageMagick**. Are you running an old version... `identify -version` will tell you.

Comment: My version is
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-03-14 http://www.imagemagick.org

-channel RGB wont work

Comment: I think that version is several years old now - probably time to upgrade.

Comment: I tried -channel RGB with IM version 7.
The result is a black image

Comment: It works for me just with `convert *.png -evaluate-sequence mean MEAN.png` under v7.

Comment: Yes, but it considders the alpha channel!

Example:

I got 3 Images with 1x1 pixel.

Image 1: 255 0 0

Image 2: 0 0 0

Image 3: 0 0 0 (alpha 0%) - this image is completely transparent!

If I do combine them with IM MEAN method I will get the following:

Result: 128 0 0 (alpha 77,777%)


But I want, that it does not considder the alpha channel. Photoshop does it like i want.

Result: 128 0 0 (alpha 100%) EDIT: BIG SORRY... I can't insert linebreaks

Comment: Your sample images don't really help your case at all - they all look pretty similar - maybe you can improve them to actually show what you mean? Instead of answering questions in the comments area (which are hard to format, as you have seen), just click `edit` under your original question and update the question.

Comment: You say you want it not to consider the alpha channel. Do you mean you want the entire output image to be opaque? Or do you mean you don't want transparent pixels to count so that when you take the mean of 3 pixels but one of them is transparent, you divide the sum by 2 rather than 3? If so, what do we do with 50% transparent pixels?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to use the alpha channels as weighting images for each image. The total fraction of white values at each pixel from all the alpha channels would be the weight to use for the average. So something like this should do what you want or at least be close.

First, cd to your directory of images. Then run the following.

```
convert *.png -evaluate-sequence mean \
\( -clone 0 -alpha off \) \
\( -clone 0 -alpha extract \) \
-delete 0 +swap -compose divide -composite result.png
```

This will work if there is some image texture at each pixel coming from al least one image. That is at a given pixel all images are not totally black (transparent).

```
compare -metric rmse result.png mean_photoshop.png null:
125.167 (0.00190993)
```

So this shows that there is about 0.2% difference between my result and what you got from photoshop

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. First you say it works fine. Then you say it only works with IM 7. Please clarify. Does it work in both IM 6 and IM 7 or only one. If only one, what are your exact IM versions.

Comment: I tested it with Ubuntu 16.04 and IM 6. The result is false. When I use Ubuntu 16.04 with IM 7 and Windows with IM 7 it works fine. Maybe something is corrupt in my Ubuntu VM with IM 6.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 IM: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 and the other one is ImageMagick 7.0.5-5

Comment: IM 6.7.7.10 is ancient -- about 200 versions old. There could have been a bug as it was undergoing some major changes during that period. I would recommend that you upgrade, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this way of working will help you get there - or at least explain the problem:

```
convert xc:"rgba(255,0,0,1)" xc:"rgba(0,0,0,1)" xc:"rgba(0,0,0,0)" -depth 8 -evaluate-sequence mean txt:
```

**Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,srgba
0,0: (21845,0,0,43690)  #550000AA  srgba(85,0,0,0.666667)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using IM 6.8.9.4 Q16 or IM 7.0.5.5 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra, this seems to work fine for me:

Make transparent image

```
convert logo: -transparent white logot.png
```

Get mean

```
convert logot.png logot.png logot.png -alpha off -evaluate-sequence mean result.png

magick logot.png logot.png logot.png -alpha off -evaluate-sequence mean result.png
```

This also seems to work:

```
convert logot.png logot.png logot.png -channel rgb -evaluate-sequence mean -alpha off result.png
```

So perhaps you need to upgrade your ImageMagick (and/or libpng?)

Can you post a zip file of some of your input images, so we can test with your images?

Comment: Here is my example: http://www.high-iso.de/other/im_mean.zip (90MB) - 
"mean_photoshop.png" is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I see is that the PNG images that you provided have black under the transparent areas and not image texture. So when you disable alpha as in my commands above, you see black and the black gets averaged into the final result. Did you use these same PNG images in Photoshop or did you have Photoshop PSD images or some other images that you used and then exported to PNG, which may have put black under the transparent areas.  Have you tried using the same PNG images in Photoshop to do the average?

In fact, you have 8-bit color (palette) images, which have one color (black) assigned to be the transparent color.